# Why is network output different after changing EC2 instance type from t2.large to m5.large?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

After detecting high latency in my application, I decided to change instance type from t2.large to m5.large. I expected some metrics to change, for example CPU utilization, but I am curious to know why Max Network Out and Max Network In went down after changing instance type? As you can see, the request stay almost the same and the code running is exactly the same:
[image]

Comment: This might be application specific. It's impossible to tell just based on the info that you have given.

Answer (score 1):

Your graphs are displaying:

- **Sum** of requests per time unit
- **Average** of CPU Utilization per time unit
- **Maximum** of Network In per time unit
- **Maximum** of Network Out per time unit

Note that the Network figures shown are a **calculated maximum**, not a `SUM`. The graph suggests that the **maximum network throughput** for each time period was lower, which could come from the traffic being more spread-out across time periods.

Larger instances have higher network bandwidths, so it *might* be that the traffic was less-throttled.

To dig deeper into the data, you could graph the `SUM` of Network traffic over each time period, rather than the `MAX1.